# F# Canopy: Can a test be excluded from the report?

Tags: f#, reporters, canopy-web-testing

I am a beginner in f# canopy UI testing and I have one small problem:

I want to exclude one test from the report. I use LiveHtmlReporter and I do not want this test to be displayed in the final table. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want the test to be *run*, but not reported? (And if so, why? I don't see a use for this, and I don't think Canopy lets you do this). Or do you just want to exclude that one test from being run? There's a way to do the latter, but I need to know a little more about your needs before I can be sure of the best way to help you.

Comment: P.S. The `canopy` tag is for a [Python library for data analysis](https://www.enthought.com/product/canopy/). For the F# Web testing tool called Canopy, use the `canopy-web-testing` tag.

Comment: Yes, I want the test to be run but not reported.
I want to use skipAllTestsOnFailure to prepare some smoke tests which eventually stop the process on failure, however, I do not want them to be present in the report if they pass.